# How to Query Azure Table storage using .Net Standard

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-table-storage, .net-standard

I have a .Net Standard client application running on UWP.

My client application contacts the server that generates a sas key like so:

```
var myPrivateStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(mystorageAccountKey);
var myPrivateTableClient = myPrivateStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
SharedAccessTablePolicy pol = new SharedAccessTablePolicy()
{
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(59),
    Permissions = SharedAccessTablePermissions.Query | SharedAccessTablePermissions.Add
};
CloudTable myPrivateTable = myPrivateTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
String sas = myPrivateTable.GetSharedAccessSignature(pol);
return sas;
```

My client application then runs the following:

```
StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(sas);

this.tableClient = new CloudTableClient(tableServiceURI, creds);
this.table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> projectionQuery = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>().Select(new string[] { "DocumentName" }).Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, cc));
 var res = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<DynamicTableEntity>(projectionQuery, null);
```

and gets the following error:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. sr
>   is mandatory. Cannot be empty

but as this is tablestorage [I dont think sr is required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-a-service-sas#specifying-the-signed-resource-blob-service-only)

and my SAS key looks fine to me:

> ?sv=2018-03-28&tn=MyTable&sig=RandomSig151235341543&st=2019-01-17T12%3A00%3A28Z&se=2019-01-17T12%3A59%3A28Z&sp=ra

so whats the problem here?

Comment: Can you share your SAS token?

Comment: @GauravMantri shared

Comment: Your SAS token looks OK to me. Can you confirm that table for which SAS token is the same as the table against which query is executed? Also, trace the request/response through a tool like Fiddler please. You will get more detailed error message in the response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is kind of stupid but I will post anyway.

I was sending the request to:

> https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/

and should have been sending the request to:

> https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/